# WM_INPUT not received when not in focus

Tags: c#, winforms, raw-input, sharpdx

I'm using Windows Forms in C# with SharpDX RawInput.

It all works fine, but when the window looses focus, the messages stop.

I've registered my own message filter with `Application.AddMessageFilter` and the messages don't even make it there once the focus is lost.

Weren't WM_INPUT messages supposed to be independent of the focus? How do I make this work when the window is in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to set the `RIDEV_INPUTSINK` flag. In SharpDX this is known as `DeviceFlags.InputSink`.

Comment: Am having a similar problem - I know this flag is the correct one to use, but when I set it in the [SharpDX demo app](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/RawInput/RawInputTrackApp/Program.cs#L49), I no longer get any input, even when the app is focused.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the demo application to still receive raw input messages even when the window isn't focused by doing this:

Replace these two lines:

```
Device.RegisterDevice(UsagePage.Generic, UsageId.GenericMouse, DeviceFlags.None);
Device.RegisterDevice(UsagePage.Generic, UsageId.GenericKeyboard, DeviceFlags.None);
```

With these two lines:

```
Device.RegisterDevice(UsagePage.Generic, UsageId.GenericMouse, DeviceFlags.InputSink, form.Handle);
Device.RegisterDevice(UsagePage.Generic, UsageId.GenericKeyboard, DeviceFlags.InputSink, form.Handle);
```

So you're changing the flag to InputSink and you're getting the handle of the window, whereas before the flag was none and no window was specified.